# Java Swing Access Class Variables From Button

Tags: java, swing

So in my Java Swing application, I need a button ActionListener to be able to access variables outside of its scope like so:

```
int x = 13;

JButton btn = new JButton("New Button");
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
});
```

but I get a variable out of scope error. How can I access it?

Comment: What is the error? Please read this first http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then edit your question.

Comment: where  did you declare `int x` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action listener is an anonymous inner class. This means that it can only use final variables from an outer scope. So, either declare x as final or pass it into the class some other way.

This should work:

```
final int x = 13;

JButton btn = new JButton("New Button");
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
});
```

Alternatively, see [Pass variables to ActionListener in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037622/pass-variables-to-actionlistener-in-java) for some other options.

Comment: So if I wanted the button to take text from a textbox and print it out, could I make a final JTextField, and call getText() on it?

Comment: Yes, that should work. All variables declared outside of an inner class must be final in order to be used inside the class.