# Local variable count defined in an enclosing scope must be final error

Tags: java, scope

I have wrote some simple code in order to increment a progress bar by one each time a button is clicked. Here is my code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class BtnProgTest extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    BtnProgTest frame = new BtnProgTest();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public BtnProgTest() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);


        JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        progressBar.setBounds(115, 114, 183, 14);   
        contentPane.add(progressBar);
     int count = 0;
    progressBar.setMaximum(100);


JButton btnProgress = new JButton("Progress");
btnProgress.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        if(count<100) {
            count++; //error here
            progressBar.setValue(count);

        }

    }
});
btnProgress.setBounds(160, 166, 89, 23);
contentPane.add(btnProgress);
    }
}
```

The error message I am receiving is "Local variable count defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final". I can't really see the scope error I would really appreciate if someone could edit my code so that the error is not there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass variables to ActionListener in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037622/pass-variables-to-actionlistener-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `count` variable on the class level and it should work.

Also, as an improvement, I would recommend using lambda expression for adding the action listener to the button (it's cleaner):

```
btnProgress.addActionListener(e -> {
    if (count < 100) {
        count++;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error stated, for any variables declared outside of `ActionListener`, it must be declared `final`. Try this work around instead:

```
public class BtnProgTest extends JFrame {

    // declare these as class's member variables
    private JProgressBar progressBar;
    private int count = 0;


    public BtnProgTest() {
        ......

        // progressBar is now a class's member variable
        this.progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        .....

        JButton btnProgress = new JButton("Progress");

        btnProgress.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                BtnProgTest.this.updateProgressBar();
            }
        });

        ......
    }


    private void updateProgressBar() {
        if (this.count < 100) {
            this.count++;
            this.progressBar.setValue(this.count);
        }
    }

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the count in your actionPerformed is unknown as you are in the "new ActionListener()" scope